# Terraform nested loop conditionnal

Tags: terraform, yaml, conditional-statements, terraform-provider-azure

I have written code that works well in order to create Azure Firewall Network Rules via Terraform. Weeks later i'm asked to add an attribute "expiration" in order to enable users to create temporary network rules.

If the expiration field is 0, means the rule is permanent, if not, i compare the date with the sysdate.

I have tried nearly every possible "for_each" with "for" and "if" combinations, but nothing seems to work. That "expiration" attribute seems inaccessible from outside the loop.

Here are the files of my code:

**main.tf**

**module.tf** (*edits must be done here, in the dynamic "rule" bloçk of the network_rule_collection block, all other files have been simplified and are here only for better understanding of the code logic*)

**variables.tf**

**net_rules.yaml**

**fw_collections.yaml**

---

Main.tf

```
locals {
  collections = yamldecode(file("../environments/fw_collections.yaml"))
  netrules   = yamldecode(file("../environments/net_rules.yaml"))
  apprules   = yamldecode(file("../environments/app_rules.yaml"))

}

module "tdf_az_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" {
  source       = "../../modules/tdf_az_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group"
  fw_policy_id = module.tdf_az_firewall_policy.firewall_policy_id
  fw_c         = local.collections.FW_Collections
  fw_nr        = local.netrules.FW_NET_Rules
  fw_ar        = local.apprules.FW_APP_Rules
  rgname       = data.azurerm_resource_group.ipgrg.name
  sub          = element(split("/", module.tdf_az_virtual_hub_module.virtual_hub_id), 2)
  depends_on   = [module.tdf_az_firewall_policy, module.tdf_az_firewall]
}
```

---

Module.tf

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "fw-prcg" {
  for_each           = var.fw_c
  name               = each.key
  firewall_policy_id = var.fw_policy_id
  priority           = each.value[0]


  dynamic "network_rule_collection" {
    for_each = { for nr, name in var.fw_nr : nr => name if nr == each.key }
    content {
      name     = each.key
      priority = each.value[0]
      action   = each.value[1]
      dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = { for x, y in var.fw_nr[each.key] : x => y.expiration if timecmp(y.expiration, timestamp()) == 1 }
        content {
          name                  = rule.value.name
          protocols             = rule.value.protocols
          source_ip_groups      = [for s in rule.value.source_ip_groups : join("/", ["/subscriptions", var.sub, "resourceGroups", var.rgname, "providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups", s])]
          destination_ip_groups = [for d in rule.value.destination_ip_groups : join("/", ["/subscriptions", var.sub, "resourceGroups", var.rgname, "providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups", d])]

          destination_ports = rule.value.destination_ports
        }
      }
    }
    }


  dynamic "application_rule_collection" {
    for_each = { for ar, name in var.fw_ar : ar => name if ar == each.key }
    content {
      name     = each.key
      priority = each.value[0]
      action   = each.value[1]
      dynamic "rule" {
        for_each = var.fw_ar[each.key]
        content {
          name = rule.value.name
          dynamic "protocols" {
            for_each = rule.value.protocols
            content {
              type = protocols.value.type
              port = protocols.value.port
            }
          }
          source_ip_groups      = [for s in rule.value.source_ip_groups : join("/", ["/subscriptions", var.sub, "resourceGroups", var.rgname, "providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups", s])]
          destination_fqdns     = rule.value.destination_fqdns
          destination_urls      = rule.value.destination_urls
          terminate_tls         = rule.value.terminate_tls
          web_categories        = rule.value.web_categories
          destination_fqdn_tags = rule.value.destination_fqdn_tags
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

---

variables.tf

```
variable "fw_policy_id" {}
variable "fw_c" {}
variable "fw_nr" {}
variable "fw_ar" {}
variable "sub" {}
variable "rgname" {}
```

---

netrules.yaml

```
FW_NET_Rules:
  Blacklist-Net:
    - name: blacklisted_inbound_ips_rule_inbound
      source_ip_groups: ["blacklisted_inbound_ips"]
      destination_ip_groups: ["Any-ip"]
      estination_ports: ["*"]
      protocols: ["Any"]
      expiration: 0
    - name: k8saas_backlisted_idps_rule_inbound
      source_ip_groups: ["k8saas_blacklist_ip_inbound"]
      destination_ip_groups: ["Any-ip"]
      destination_ports: ["*"]
      protocols: ["Any"]
      expiration: 0
  Mobility:
    - name: Mobility-LAN-VNET
      source_ip_groups: ["Mobility-LAN"]
      destination_ip_groups: ["Mobility-VNET"]
      destination_ports: ["443"]
      protocols: ["TCP"]
      expiration: "2022-12-12T00:00:00Z"
    - name: Mobility-LAN-To-Data
      source_ip_groups: ["Mobility-LAN"]
      destination_ip_groups: ["Data-VNET"]
      destination_ports: ["443"]
      protocols: ["TCP"]
      expiration: "2022-12-12T00:00:00Z"
```

---

fw_collections.yaml

```
FW_Collections:
  Blacklist-Net: [100, "Deny"]
  Mobility: [105, "Allow"]
```

Comment: I don't see where you tried to add the `expiration` field. Are there any errors?

Comment: Hello, its in the net_rules.yaml file, there an the expiration field for each rule

Comment: I can see that, but you haven't tried to access it in the terraform code?

Comment: look in the module.tf

Comment: for_each = { for x, y in var.fw_nr[each.key] : x => y.expiration if timecmp(y.expiration, timestamp()) == 1 }

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand either. You say that you can't access the `expiration` field outside of the loop, but you're only attempting to access it in the dictionary comprehension. What does "nothing seems to work" mean? How is it behaving, vs what you're expecting?

Comment: as you can see there are four rule blocks in the yaml file. the module.tf file parses it and create a network rule for each block. now, the goal is that i want terraform to check if the condition is met (expiration date) in order to execute/or not, the according rule block